# Textmate - select and modify matching HTML Tags

Tags: html, textmate, shortcut

Textmate - Is there a shortcut for selecting matching HTML tags or another way to quickly remove/modify an existing begin and end tag at once?

Kind of like SHIFT + CTRL + W ... but for tags that already exist in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this post](http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2007-November/023274.html) will link you to a bundle that can do that with one of its included macros.

Here's a [direct link to the macro file](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/Experimental.tmbundle/Macros/Select%20Balanced%20(HT|X)ML%20Tags.tmMacro).

Comment: If you're in a hurry and don't want to read the mail download the macro directly from here http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/Experimental.tmbundle/Macros/Select%20Balanced%20(HT%7cX)ML%20Tags.tmMacro